# Angular Material MatDatePicker not displaying correct date

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material, angular-material-datetimepicker

So I'm using the angular material datepicker in a form to get the user's birth date. It works most of the time but when manually typing in dates in a certain format, it doesn't display the correct date. For example if I type in `2000-01-15` and click away, it changes the date in the input to show `1/14/2000`, however if I type in `01/15/2000`, it correctly changes the input to display `1/15/2000`. Furthermore, if I just type in a year to the input like `2000`, it changes the input to display `12/31/1999`.

Here's html for the datepicker, not doing any logic on it in the controller.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input id="birthDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="birthDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="birthDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

If anyone has any ideas or has ran into this before any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The behavior is the same on the Angular Material docs as well: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Answer (score 2):

Your missing `#birthDate`in mat-datepicker

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input id="birthDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="birthDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="birthDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #birthDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```